# pandas to_sql is slow when SQL trace/extended events is running

Tags: sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, sentry

We use pandas `to_sql` a lot to load csv files into existing tables. we don't have an issue generally since we use `fast_executemany=True`. A 40MB (350K records) csv file is loaded in 10 seconds.

But we've started encountering an issue where `to_sql` is excruciatingly slow even with `fast_executemany`. It appears due to SQL Sentry SQL Monitor which runs a SQL trace behind the scenes.

But I can reproduce with a simple trace without SQL Sentry.

- When I run it on prod server (same file and data types), which is monitored with a trace by SQL Sentry, it runs for over 10 minutes before I stop it (there's no blocking - i can see the table counts slowly increasing).
- When I run it on dev server (which doesn't have SQL Sentry), it finishes in 10-15sec.
- When I run it on dev server again but with extended events capturing (or profiler trace) running, it runs slowly just like prod. If I pause the trace, it's immediately fast again.

Why would a trace have such a huge effect? Because of the large number of `sp_execute` statements it has to generate? Is there a workaround?

I'll talk to the DBAs about what events they're capturing on prod and if they can reduce the overhead. It's an all-day monitoring suite.

I also see some different results when I have trace running and also use chunksize argument in to_sql.

- pandas 2.0 (but also 1.4)
- pyodbc 4.0.35
- SQL Server 2017

```
import urllib
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd
host = 'my_server'
schema = 'workdb'

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
                                 "SERVER=" + host + ";"
                                "DATABASE=" + schema + ";"
                               "trusted_connection=yes;")

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params), fast_executemany=True)
csv_path = r'C:\Users\me\Desktop\somefile.csv' # 40mb file

df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, dtype_backend='pyarrow')  # pyarrow for pandas 2.0+.
df.to_sql(con=engine, name="target_table", schema="import", index=False, if_exists='append')
```

```
The CSV file is something like this:
day,ds,gender,age_group,country,device,dormancy_cohort,reg_id,uid
2023-04-17,20230417,1,0,GBR,Android,4,03f9dfza868sb58zza0s8cd0d6f4,b2406ea4da557s9a65926az804
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace really does have that much impact. I was expecting execute_many to be low impact similar to SSIS Fast Load (aka Bulk Insert) but that's not the case.  It still has to generate many `sp_prepare` calls

Simply turning off the monitoring (the SQL trace) on production decreased a prod script from 8 minutes to 40 seconds, 8x faster!

edit: Even when SQL Sentry is using Extended Events instead of SQL Trace, performance is still slow using `to_sql`.

If monitoring is still required (for auditing or other reasons), there is a workaround provided by [@gordthompson](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/1fb0f1c3f5edbf6192e596de8350f205) which uses OPENJSON.

```
# Alternative to_sql() *method* for mssql+pyodbc or mssql+pymssql
#
# adapted from https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-sql-method
#
# version 1.2 - 2023-05-08
from datetime import date
import json

import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa


def mssql_insert_json(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    """
    Execute SQL statement inserting data via OPENJSON
    Parameters
    ----------
    table : pandas.io.sql.SQLTable
    conn : sqlalchemy.engine.Engine or sqlalchemy.engine.Connection
    keys : list of str
        Column names
    data_iter : Iterable that iterates the values to be inserted
    """
    # build dict of {"column_name": "column_type"}
    col_dict = {
        str(col.name): "varchar(max)"
        if str(col.type) == "TEXT"
        else "nvarchar(max)"
        if str(col.type) == "NTEXT"
        else str(col.type)
        for col in table.table.columns
    }
    columns = ", ".join([f"[{k}]" for k in keys])
    if table.schema:
        table_name = f"[{table.schema}].[{table.name}]"
    else:
        table_name = f"[{table.name}]"

    json_data = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]

    with_clause = ",\n".join(
        [
            f"[{col_name}] {col_type} '$.\"{col_name}\"'"
            for col_name, col_type in col_dict.items()
        ]
    )
    placeholder = "?" if conn.dialect.paramstyle == "qmark" else "%s"
    sql = f"""\
    INSERT INTO {table_name} ({columns})
    SELECT {columns}
    FROM OPENJSON({placeholder})
    WITH
    (
    {with_clause}
    );
    """

    conn.exec_driver_sql(sql, (json.dumps(json_data, default=str),))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # =============
    # USAGE EXAMPLE
    # =============

    # note: fast_executemany=True is not required
    engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@mssql_199")

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [(1, "Alfa", date(2001, 1, 1)), (2, "Bravo", date(2002, 2, 2))],
        columns=["id", "my text", "date added"],
    )

    df.to_sql(
        "##tmp",
        engine,
        index=False,
        if_exists="append",
        method=mssql_insert_json,
    )

    # check result
    with engine.begin() as connection:
        print(connection.exec_driver_sql("SELECT * FROM ##tmp").all())
        # [(1, 'Alfa', datetime.date(2001, 1, 1)), (2, 'Bravo', datetime.date(2002, 2, 2))]

"""The INSERT statement generated for this example is:
INSERT INTO [##tmp] ([id], [my text], [date added])
SELECT [id], [my text], [date added]
FROM OPENJSON(?)
WITH
(
[id] BIGINT '$."id"',
[my text] varchar(max) '$."my text"',
[date added] DATE '$."date added"'
);
"""
```

More discussion here:

- https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/discussions/1215

Lastly, consider using `bcp` if you are able to.